# How Node.JS handles multiple requests without blocking?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I have been using Node.JS for a while and just wonder how it handles when multiple clients causing some blocking / time consuming works to response ?

Consider the following situation
1- There are many endpoints and one of them is time consuming and responds in a few seconds.
2- Suppose, 100 clients simultaneously make requests to my endpoints, which one of them takes a considerable amount of time.

Does that endpoint block all event loop and make other requests wait ?

Or , In general, Do requests block each other in Node.JS ?

If not , why ? It is single-threaded, why do not they block each other ?

Comment: Node is not single threaded, but no 2 lines of Javascript will run at the same time. A lot has been written about how this works. What have you found so far? It might help to share some of your own research, to contextualize where the confusion might lie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.Js **does use** threads behind the scenes to perform I/O operations. To be more spesific to your question - there will be a limit where a client will have to wait for an idle thread to perform a new I/O task.

You can make an easy toy example - running several I/O tasks concurrently (by using Promise.all for instance) and measure the time it takes for each to finish. Then add a new task and repeat.
At some point you'll notice two groups. For example 4 requests took 250ms and the other 2 took 350ms (and there you get "requests blocking each other").

Node.Js is commonly refered as single threaded for its default CPU-operations excecution (in contrary to its Non-blocking I/O architecture). therefore it won't be very wise using it for intensive CPU operations, but very efficient when it comes to I/O operations.